# Change chart titile in excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to select some charts and replace a common part in their titles

I try to write this code but not work!

```
Sub ChangeTitelFormula()
''' Just do active chart
If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    '' There is no active chart
    MsgBox "Please select a chart and try again.", vbExclamation, _
        "No Chart Selected"
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim OldString As String, NewString As String, strTemp As String
Dim mySrs As ChartObject

OldString = InputBox("Enter the string to be replaced:", "Enter old string")

If Len(OldString) > 1 Then
    NewString = InputBox("Enter the string to replace " & """" _
        & OldString & """:", "Enter new string")
    '' Loop through all series
    For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.ChartObjects
        strTemp = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(mySrs.ChartTitle.Text, _
            OldString, NewString)
        mySrs.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = strTemp
    Next
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing to be replaced.", vbInformation, "Nothing Entered"
End If
End Sub
```

any help ?
Thanks

Comment: "Do not work" is not helpful. Please explain *how* it is not working. Error messages?

Comment: no error messages. but title doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

I performed minor surgery on your code. This routine does just the active chart:

```
Sub FindReplaceForChartTitle()
  Dim OldString As String, NewString As String, strTemp As String

  '' Just do active chart
  If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Please select a chart and try again.", vbExclamation, _
      "No Chart Selected"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  OldString = InputBox("Enter the string to be replaced:", "Enter old string")

  If Len(OldString) > 1 Then
    NewString = InputBox("Enter the string to replace " & """" _
      & OldString & """:", "Enter new string")

    strTemp = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text, _
      OldString, NewString)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = strTemp
  Else
    MsgBox "Nothing to be replaced.", vbInformation, "Nothing Entered"
  End If
End Sub
```

This routine does all charts in the active sheet:

```
Sub FindReplaceForChartTitles()
  Dim OldString As String, NewString As String, strTemp As String
  Dim chob As ChartObject

  OldString = InputBox("Enter the string to be replaced:", "Enter old string")

  If Len(OldString) > 1 Then
    NewString = InputBox("Enter the string to replace " & """" _
      & OldString & """:", "Enter new string")

    For Each chob In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
      If chob.Chart.HasTitle Then
        strTemp = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(chob.Chart.ChartTitle.Text, _
          OldString, NewString)
        chob.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = strTemp
      End If
    Next
  Else
    MsgBox "Nothing to be replaced.", vbInformation, "Nothing Entered"
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `ActiveChart`  has no `ChartObjects`. 
Try `ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text`

Comment: doesn't work !
    For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text

Comment: Get rid of the `for each` loop. Simply access the title of the ActiveChart

Comment: but i want to change all of them at once?

Comment: Which "all"? All selected? All Charts in your Worksheet? All Charts in your Workbook?

Comment: All Charts in your Workshee